# Error in the sentence

Tags: error

(a) Now a days
(b) the accidents of diabetes 
(c) among urban children 
(d) is on the rise. 
(e) No error

Sorry for this silly question.

I am little bit confused where is the error in the above sentence.
Please suggest

Comment: Hint: is diabetes an accident or an incident?

Comment: I am asking where is the error.in the above sentence

Comment: And I am giving you a hint, the error may not be grammatical, but correct word usage

Comment: _Nowadays_ should be one word, not three.

Comment: @J.R. That's true, but it's probably not the error she is being asked to find.

Comment: @Peter - That's why I upvoted your comments before posting mine.

Comment: I am not getting yet

Comment: Here answer is option a? But in question it is asking for grammatical error. If no error then option e

Comment: I can see how your might be confused if the definition for **accident** you found was "an unfortunate incident that happens unexpectedly and unintentionally" (just searched it), since even though getting diabetes is unfortunate for the person who got it.  Diabetes does not happen accidentally.  An **accident** is more like when two cars crash. An **incident** is when something happens and is countable. @J.R. was pointing out an incorrect spelling in (a)

Comment: Thanks Peter I got it.so error is present in option b.am I right ?? @peter

Comment: But you should know why it is an error.

Comment: Yes got it diabetes is not an accident @peter

Comment: @peter This is one of those cases where dictionary definitions can be misleading. I presume few people know that they will get diabetes, and fewer still deliberately set out to get it, so it is "unexpected" and "unintentional". But we would not normally say that you got a disease "by accident", even though it sounds like this fits the definition you quote.

Comment: Shouldn't it be *are* instead of *is*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors.

Line 1 should be one word, [nowadays](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/nowadays?s=t)

Line 2 should be [incidence](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/incidence?s=t), not accidents